# BigCommerce API issue with page limit

Tags: php, api, curl, bigcommerce

I am working on a task in which i need to fetch bigcommerce products check for product url's to generate sitemap.xml file

Actually there are 180000 products on site so i will need to create multiple sitemap xml files and a single index (sitemap.xml) file.

I completed all script to do that, i am grouping 50000 url's in every sitemap xml files created.

When i run it, once it was executed correctly and created 4 sitemap files.
all was worked fine.

But now i am unable to execute it coz after running for sometime it gives me network error (Something like bigcommerce connection lost)

The issue is that there is a limit while calling bigcommerce api, coz we need to send it a page no and at a time only 250 products are fetched.

so i asked to bigcommerce support person for extending limit for fetching products in a single api call. he suggested me to use loop and informed me that there is no any solution for it, we can fetch only 250 products at a time.

its difficult to fetch 180000 products in single script calling api in loop.
but in my case its compulsory for me to do that in a sigle script (i need to set that script as a cron job).

Is there any solution do accomplish this task without any network error.
Any bigcommerce expert here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Hey guys ..... any bigcommerce api expert?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to pull all the products in the store i was working on,
As it stands, they do have a max number of products per request,

What you need to do instead is to use a filter, and loop... i believe there is no other way to do this.

```
$count = Bigcommerce::getProductsCount()/250;

for($x=1;$x<$count;$x++){
$filter = array("page" => $x, "limit" => 250);
$products = Bigcommerce::getProducts($filter);

// All your code goes here

}
```

I hope this answers your question.
Though this reply is a bit late, it might help someone

Comment: I already had that script you mentioned above, but its really hectic if we are trying to fetch such a large amount of products, by the way i solved this issue with my own alternative method (dumping data into db) and its working fine.

Comment: You're welcome Sunny,
Apparently iam also running into Some funny Network error ...
Did you manage to find out why this happens?
I have been in contact with BC API Support but they havent been able to understand why i keep getting that error when making PUT requests