# Bigcommerce paging through orders

Tags: bigcommerce

I am pulling back one months of data using:
        $page = 1;
    $filter = array('page' => $page,'limit' => 250,'min_date_created' => $startDate );
    $orders = Bigcommerce::getOrders($filter);

I am passing in $startDate as 2014-01-06 (which works for the orders).

The order has approx 600 so I need to page through the results.

I am using:

```
$filterCount = array ('status_id' => 2 ,'min_date_created' => $startDate);
$count = Bigcommerce::getOrdersCount($filterCount);
```

I should then be able to divide $count by 250 to give me my number of pages. However $count is always 8773 no matter how I play around with $filterCount.

Am I doing something dumb here ?

Mr Warby.

Answer (score 1):

You want to call getOrders with your filter parameters instead of getOrdersCount as that resource always returns the total number of orders.

Comment: Hi @LaurenceB. The problem is if there are more than 250 orders and I use getOrders I only see the first 250 ie page1. Unless I'm missing something. You say 'getOrders returns the total number of orders'. How do I get this figure. Mr Warby

Comment: It's a two step process. First get the total orders count (which you are), divide by 250 to get the number of pages. (Don't forget to add +1 to the page count to catch any remaining orders). Then you call getOrders with the page=x filter within a for loop. At least that's how I do it.

Comment: Sorry, thinking on this further I thought I should clarify my response: still use getOrdersCount to get the total number of orders, then divide by 250 to get the number of pages, then add +1 to catch any remaining orders. Once you have that number, use getOrders within a for loop with the page=x and limit=250 filters to page through the results.

Comment: Hi @LaurenceB, thanks for the input. The problem is I get rowcount of  8773 not matter what settings I use. So when I change min_date_created I still get 8773. So I cannot use the method you state above.

Comment: Are you using any other filters besides page and limit for the filter in your foreach loop?  Don't use filters in your getOrdersCount call either. I'm using the oAuth2 version of the API and working in C# and it looks like you're using the 'legacy'API and PHP so I found this which seems to be similar to your situation. I hope it might help out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183830

Comment: Could you please post the code you have now after making the changes I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code you are using the PHP Library.
Looking at the `getCount` method it doesn't take a 'filter' argument.

```
 public static function getCount($path)
    {
        $response = self::connection()->get(self::$api_path . $path);
        if ($response == false || is_string($response)) {
            return $response;
        }
        return $response->count;
    }
```

As you said I would use `$reponse->count / 250` to give you your pages.
Instead of `+1` to this I would use `$pages = ceil($reponse->count / 250)` then inside your `FOR` statement use `LESS THAN EQUAL TOO` and this will always give you the correct amount of pages.

When looping through the pages check for no reponse as your are filtering it between dates the actual pages needed is likely to be a lot less. if an empty object is received you could then break the loop. (I think they are sorted oldest -> newest).

Hope this helps.